# Google Authorship not displaying

Tags: google, rich-snippets, author, google-authorship

A few months back I set to the task of verifying my blog content for Google Authorship. I'm fairly confident I've ticked all the boxes and when I test my posts with the Google Structured Data tool it informs me that [Authorship is working for this webpage](http://www.google.com/webmasters/tools/richsnippets?url=http://blog.fraser-hart.co.uk/jquery-parallax-scrolling/&html=).

It has been like this for around 2 months but I am still not seeing my authorship profile in the search results. Do a search for "**jQuery Parallax Scrolling Tutorial**" and you will see my blog post near the top of the results but no authorship data.

***Can anyone suggest why this is not appearing when Google itself tells me that everything is in order?*** Thanks

Comment: Note that as of 8/28/2014, [Authorship markup is no longer supported in web search](https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/6083347?rd=1). See [this](http://searchengineland.com/goodbye-google-authorship-201975) for more.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's most likely to do with Google *choosing* not to display your image... as you've said you have ticked all the boxes, the rich snippets tool is working too.

It may be to do with the fact only 4 people have you in their circles which could indicate to Google that your profile isn't regularly maintained therefor not worth linking to that search result.

Carry on doing what you're doing for new posts and work on building you G+ account!

Comment: Excellent. I thought that could have been the issue. Thanks for confirming that I've not done anything wrong. I'll get to work adding people to my circles. Anyone reading this, feel free to add me to help me along :)