# Microformatting accepted, then ignored

Tags: search-results

I have implemented microformatting in one of our websites for our address, breadcrumbs and reviews that we collect from our customers.

After we launched the new website using the microformatting Google accepted all and produced perfect formatted rich snippets. After about a month all got ignored and queries returned 'normal' snippets again.

The Rich Snippet Testing tools indicates all is marked up correctly. Is there anything else I can do? What is the best practice in this matter?

Comment: Did you happen to switch to XHTML for your website?

Comment: We didn't switch. It was XHTML before and after the implementation.

Answer (score 1):

This may be a situation similar to [Google Authorship not displaying](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/43975/google-authorship-not-displaying/43976).
According to the answer there, Google may choose to ignore rich snippet markup on new sites.  In that case it was author markup and the suggestion was to get more followers on Google+.

In the case of your new website, you may need to get additional authority through inbound links and social media.